# typescript - Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to make this function not yield the compiler error.

The function takes the duration in ms, and prepend hours/minutes/seconds with a 0 if the number is less than 10.

```
private msToTime(duration:any):string {
    var milliseconds:string = String(parseInt((duration%1000)/100))
    var seconds:string = String(parseInt((duration/1000)%60))
    var minutes:string = String(parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60))
    var hours:string = String(parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24))

    hours   = (parseInt(hours) < 10)   ? "0" + hours   : hours;
    minutes = (parseInt(minutes) < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (parseInt(seconds) < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried following code and compiler doesn't return any errors.

```
private msToTime(duration:any):string {
    var milliseconds:string = String((duration%1000)/100)
    var seconds:string = String((duration/1000)%60)
    var minutes:string = String((duration/(1000*60))%60)
    var hours:string = String((duration/(1000*60*60)%24)

    hours   = (parseInt(hours) < 10)   ? "0" + hours   : hours;
    minutes = (parseInt(minutes) < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (parseInt(seconds) < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `parseInt((duration%1000)/100)`, where `(duration%1000)/100` is int already, so you can just drop this method, and use

```
var milliseconds:string = String((duration%1000)/100)
var seconds:string = String((duration/1000)%60)
var minutes:string = String((duration/(1000*60))%60)
var hours:string = String((duration/(1000*60*60))%24)
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` takes a string input. For your purpose here, use `Math.floor()`,

Answer (score -1):

parseInt function Argument of type is string
so , you can do like this :
var milliseconds:string =String(parseInt((duration%1000)/100).toString());